# Custom Sign-Up page redirects to LoginPage in React-Admin

Tags: material-ui, react-router-dom, react-admin, react-final-form

**GOAL:**
A user clicks a link tag `<Link>` from Custom Login Page directing to a Sign-Up Custom Page. In Sign-Up page, after Form submission in OnSubmit, redirects the user to Login Page or any page inside of React-Admin.

**PROBLEM:**
In the OnSubmit function, the redirect doesn't work and has no effect. It unexpectedly re-renders the form and stay on the Sign-Up page.

```js
//./CustomRoutes.js

<Route exact path="/signUp" component={SignUp} noLayout />

//./App.js


<Admin theme={theme}
    initialState={initialState}
    layout={MyLayout}
    catchAll={NotFound}
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    loginPage={SignIn}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    customRoutes={customRoutes}
  > ... </Admin> 

//./SignUp.js  

  async function onSubmit(data) {
         <Redirect
           to={{
         pathname: "/login",
         state: { referrer: { p: data.password, u: data.userName } }
       }}
     />
   }

  return (
            <Form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              validate={v => validate(v, translate)}
              render={formProps => {
   
                return (
                  <form
                    onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit}
                    noValidate
                    className={classes.form}
                  > 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional rendering and State Hook. The Redirect component needs to place inside the main body of the components for rendering.

```js
//./SignUp.js  

  
const [redirectToLoginPage, setRedirectToLoginPage] = useState(false);

  async function onSubmit(data) {
         setRedirectToLoginPage(true);
     />
   }

  return (
            <Form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              validate={v => validate(v, translate)}
              render={formProps => {
   
                return (
                  redirectToLoginPage ? 
                  <Redirect
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/login"
                      }}: 

                  <form
                    onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit}
                    noValidate
                    className={classes.form}
                  > 
...
```